# Почему RewriteRule вызывает нежелательный редирект?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Хочу что бы при запросе страницы domen.ru/old/какие-то_латинские_буквы/ открывалась страница domen.ru/new/какие-то_латинские_буквы/ но url оставался старым.
htaccеss выглядит вот так:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^old/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/new/$1/ [L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

При открытии страниц вида domen.ru/old/primer/ происходит 302 редирект, который мне не нужен. Почему?

Comment: А зачем там `https://...`?

Comment: Без https:// даже редирект не срабатывает